# Java NoClassDefFoundError, is it failing to import?

Tags: java

When I try to execute my app:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/samsung/b2b/fs/Ma
croMgmt$1
        at com.samsung.b2b.fs.MacroMgmt.execte(MacroMgmt.java:150)
        at com.samsung.b2b.fs.FSMgmt.main(FSMgmt.java:34)
```

I wonder if MacroMgmt.java:150 means the line where the error is, which is:

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;    
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

......

public void execte()
{
  FilenameFilter fileFilter = new FilenameFilter() // Line 150
  {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
    {
      return name.endsWith("prn");
    }
  };
 .......
```

Could be that the compiler isn't linking that import?

What I did from the beggining:

Extracted a JAR from Samsung, modified it.

Then ran: `C:\Users\Win7\Desktop\MassUploadSource>javac -cp "commons-io-2.4.jar;opencsv-2.3
.jar;com\samsung\b2b\fs;." com\samsung\b2b\fs\FSMgmt.java`

Then copied the folders with `.class`.

Then ran this:

```
C:\Users\Win7\Desktop\source>jar cfm "FileStorage.jar" MANIFEST.MF au\com\bytecode\opencsv\CSVIterator.class com\samsung\b2b\fs\FSMgmt.class com\samsung\b2b\fs\MacroMgmt.class au\com\bytecode\opencsv\CSVParser.class commons-io-2.4.jar`
```

Then replaced the original JAR. What I see missing from the original JAR is a `org.eclipse.jdr.internal.jarinjarloader`

The manifest is this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.samsung.b2b.fs.FSMgmt
Class-Path: commons-io-2.4.jar
```

Comment: The import is found, you would have a compile error otherwise. It is more likely to be a packaging issue.

Comment: Compiler found it but not the Classloader (at runtime).  Are you sure it is in your application's classpath?

Comment: @Shlublu those java.io classes, where are "put" when compiled? Inside the one that has the `main` method?

Comment: Are you using maven to resolve dependencies?

Comment: @Andreas I am using command line only, its the first time I use java

Comment: @blurfus What do you mean with if its in my application classpath? I have this in the manifest: `Class-Path: commons-io-2.4.jar`

Comment: @Jorge What is missing here is not from the `java.io` package. The missing class is the first inner anonymous class (`$1`) of `com.samsung.b2b.fs.MacroMgmt`. The funny thing is that `com.samsung.b2b.fs.MacroMgmt` itself looks found according to this stack trace. Not sure, but I think the jar file that embeds `com.samsung.b2b.fs.*` is not properly or not completely accessible by the classloader. How did you package your app?

Comment: There are easily 20 distinct reasons for NoClassDefFoundError -- it's a "garbage" exception.  *Generally* (there are exceptions) it means that the named class's .class file *was* found, but something went south before the class could be fully loaded.  Most often the problem is mismatched jar files, but there are many other potential scenarios.

Comment: @Jorge Yes and is the application and the `commons-io-2.4.jar` side-by-side? usually, I keep all my jar files in a `/lib` folder and on my manifest, I use: `Class-Path: /lib/commons-io-2.4.jar` etc.  When running from the command line, I execute the entry point of my app.  I.e. `java -jar path/to/my/jarfile.jar`

Comment: @Jorge Hard to tell exacty, but thanks to your update it sounds like there was an issue when modifying the jar. Some required .class look unaccessible to the classloader. But more generally speaking, it is not a good practice to explode a 3rd party jar to modify and repackage it. It is prone (like now) to engender many problems, and sometimes it is simply against the licence of the lib (I don't know for this one). In short: either you use a jar as it is or you modify the source should it be opensource.

Comment: Well "jar cfm" is not packaging the anonymous (named "$1") class.

Comment: A simple check: `jar -tvf your-jar.jar`.  If it does not include the file `com/samsung/b2b/fs/MacroMgmt$1.class` then you did something strange when you packaged the jar -- you left out the required `.class` file for the anonymous class.

Comment: can you confirm the manifest was included? I seem to remember that the format for using the `m` option was `jar cmf existing-manifest jar-file input-file(s)`

Comment: @robermann Thanks I thought the $1 where some kind of hidden files that wasn't classes, now the error is passed but a similar one with `CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(this.targetFile));` was found. I will try to see what is going on

Comment: In your manifest you should add the further runtime dependency jar containing au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader, that is: `Class-Path: commons-io-2.4.jar opencsv-2.3.jar`